# Secure XML access with c# events

Tags: c#, .net, xml, events, linq-to-xml

Let's say I need to provide class that performs CRUD operations for entities stored in XML file. Problem is this CRUD methods will be called from events.
Do I need to use lock keyword to secure app from multiple access exception?

I provided some example code, and i would appreciate if someone could look into this to tell if this is proper way to do this.

```cs
private static readonly object SyncObject = new object();

public void Delete(MyFile entity)
{
    if (entity != null)
    {
        lock (SyncObject)
        {
            XDocument xDocument;
            using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(MyFileXmlPath))
            {
                xDocument = XDocument.Load(stream);
            }
            xDocument.Descendants("ArrayOfMyFile")
                     .Elements()
                     .Where(e => Convert.ToInt32(e.Attribute("Id").Value) == entity.Id)
                     .Remove();
            xDocument.Save(MyFileXmlPath);
        }
    }
}

public IEnumerable<MyFile> GetAll()
{
    XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(MyFileXmlPath);
    List<MyFile> MyFiles = xDocument
        .Root
        .Descendants("MyFile")
        .Select(f => new MyFile
        {
            Id = Convert.ToInt32(f.Attribute("Id").Value),
            FilePath = f.Element("FilePath").Value,
            //... other properties
        })
        .ToList();
    return MyFiles;
}

public void Insert(MyFile entity)
{
    if (entity != null)
    {
        lock (SyncObject)
        {
            XDocument xDocument;
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(MyFileXmlPath))
                {
                    xDocument = XDocument.Load(stream);
                }
                entity.Id = GetFreeId(xDocument);
                MyFile fileToSave = (MyFile)entity;
                XElement newFile = MapMyFile(fileToSave);
                xDocument.Root.Add(newFile);
                xDocument.Save(MyFileXmlPath);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                //...
            }
        }             
    }
}

public void Update(MyFile entity)
{
    if (entity != null)
    {
        lock (SyncObject)
        {
            XDocument xDocument;
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(MyFileXmlPath))
                {
                    xDocument = XDocument.Load(stream);
                }
                XElement updatedFile = xDocument.Descendants("ArrayOfMyFile")
                         .Elements()
                         .Where(e => Convert.ToInt32(e.Attribute("Id").Value) == entity.Id)
                         .FirstOrDefault();

                if (updatedFile != null)
                {
                    updatedFile.ReplaceWith(MapMyFile(entity));
                }
                xDocument.Save(MyFileXmlPath);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                //...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not get cross-threading and locking confused.  A lock is needed to prevent two or more processes from changing the same data at the same time.  It doesn't prevent a cross-thread exception which occurs when the Net library detects multiple processes running the same code.

Comment: @jdweng If so, is there a way to prevent problem which I described?

Comment: You need to use Invoke to prevent a crosslink exception.